# Python generic buffer datatype access

Tags: python, arrays, polymorphism, byte, bit

In Python, is there any existing library-based method to polymorphically treat a buffer as being an array of any datatype -- including bits, bytes, WORDs, DWORDs, etc. -- without copying the buffer?  I have an application where I want to be able to set arbitrary ranges of bits in a stream to any unsigned value.

For example, if the buffer in bytes is `[0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 ...]` and I want to set absolute little-endian bits 27:11 to the unsigned little-endian value 54321, then the buffer in bytes becomes `[0x01, 0x8A, 0xA1, 0x06, 0x05, 0x06 ...]`.  The low-level details of read-modify-writing the bytes should be abstracted out.  I may then want to have a WORD (uint16) view of the data as `[0x8A01, 0x06A1, 0x0605, ...]` and change some of the elements that way.

Do any good public Python libraries provide this capability?

Answer (score 0):

oh, you mean the type to be mutable?

well lists are mutable, so why not use those?

But if you really want to work with bits, here's an example 
http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays

It uses BitArrays - you should be able to figure out everything from the example.

[EDIT]:
for inserting bits wherever you want:

```
import array
a=array.array('I')
a.append(5) #adds 1 element

a.extend([2,3,3,4,5,5,4]) #adds another 7 elements

a[3:6] = [6,6,6] #replaces 3 elements with the 3 6s
```

is this all u need?

Comment: What about all the functionality I mentioned of reading and setting arbitrary bit ranges, bytes, WORDs, etc.?

Comment: if you check out that lib, you'll get to array.array('I'), with the methods .insert, .extend. those seem to be useful to solving your problem, but as to replacing sections of the array, i don't know that ....yet

Comment: I don't believe the array.array module gives you access to raw absolute-bit-ranges like I specified.  You can use it to convert between the types that it supports including bytes/shorts, but you have to convert to a string and then back to another array.array object, and it looks like the types may not be uniform between platforms and Python builds.  What about my example of splicing the number 54321 into bits 27:11 of the buffer `[0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 ...]` to make it `[0x01, 0x8A, 0xA1, 0x06, 0x05, 0x06 ...]`?  Is there a library-based way to do that?